# Перезапись значения структуры tm

Tags: c

После присваивания значения указателю `local2` перезаписывается ранее присвоенное значение указателя `local`

---

Пожалуйста объясните природу этой перезаписи

---

### Задание:

*Создать функцию, вычисляющую промежуток времени между двумя отметками времени в виде количества часов, минут и секунд. Отметки времени функция должна получать через параметры структурного типа, а результат возвращать в виде значения структурной переменной.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
// описание функции
struct tm timegap(struct tm * lc1, struct tm * lc2)
{
struct tm res;
res = *lc2;
res.tm_hour = lc1->tm_hour - lc2->tm_hour;
res.tm_min  = lc1->tm_min  - lc2->tm_min;
res.tm_sec  = (lc1->tm_sec)  - (lc2->tm_sec);

return res;
}

void main ()
{
 // объявление переменных
 time_t crt_time;
 struct tm *local,*local2,result;

 // отметка времени
 getch();
 crt_time = time(NULL);
 local = localtime(&crt_time);
 printf("%s\n",asctime(local));
 // отметка времени №2
 getch();
 crt_time = time(NULL);
 local2 = localtime(&crt_time);
 //в этом месте наглядно виден факт перезаписи
 printf("%s\n",asctime(local2));
 printf("%s\n",asctime(local));
 // функции выводят одинаковые значения


/*  
    result = timegap(local2,local);
    printf("%s\n",asctime(&result));
*/
 }
```

Comment: Скорее всего дело в том, что вы пердаете не значение переменной, а по ссылке. Что произойдет если заменить `localtime(&crt_time)` на `localtime(crt_time)`?

Comment: @NikolajSarry там нет никакой ссылки. Это взятие адреса. И язык вообще C, где ссылок отродясь не видели.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что результат [`localtime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/) есть указатель на внутренний для реализации языка объект, который может быть изменен другими вызовами функций:

> The returned value points to an internal object whose validity or value may be altered by any subsequent call to `gmtime` or `localtime`.

Если нужно сохранить значение, то следует сохранять не указатель, а значение:

```
struct tm local = *localtime(&crt_time);
```

Answer (score 1):

Из MSDN

> Both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of `gmtime`, `mktime`, `mkgmtime`, and `localtime` all use a single `tm` structure per thread for the conversion. Each call to one of these routines destroys the result of the previous call.

Что в переводе значит

> Обе 32 и 64 битные версии функций `gmtime`, `mktime`, `mkgmtime`, и `localtime` используют для конвертации одну `tm` структуру на поток. Каждый вызов одной из этих функций уничтожает результат, полученный при предыдущем вызове.