# Поддерживается ли функция localtime_s в трансляторе GCC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, visual-studio-2017

Добрый день.

Пользуюсь в основном Visual Studio, и с некоторых пор Visual Studio с маниакальным упорством настаивает, чтобы вместо localtime все применяли localtime_s из-за незащищенности localtime от использования в многопоточных приложениях. В версии Visual Studio 2017 это предупреждение переведено в ранг ошибки компилятора.

Все бы ничего, но иногда нужно чтобы код транслировался и под GCC. Поэтому я решил проверить, поддерживается ли localtime_s в GCC. Я взял онлайн транслятор GCC http://cpp.sh/ и написал программу:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{

struct tm *ptr;
struct tm structtime;
time_t lt;
lt = time(NULL);

ptr = localtime(&lt);
printf(asctime(ptr));

ptr = localtime_s(&structtime,&lt);
printf(asctime(&structtime));

  std::string name;
  std::cout << "What is your name? ";
  getline (std::cin, name);
  std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";
}
```

При попытки трансляции в строке

```
ptr = localtime_s(&structtime,&lt);
```

транслятор сообщил мне, что:

> 17:34: error: 'localtime_s' was not declared in this scope

Соответственно вопросы:

1. Поддерживается ли localtime_s в GCC?
2. Может быть нужен другой хедер, не time.h?

Спасибо.

UPD1:

На других онлайн GCC трансляторах таких как:

https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

https://ideone.com/

тоже не работает localtime_s. Даже если определить все указанные макросы.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/574448/Перезапись-значения-структуры-tm/574452

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как сказано на [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime):

> As with all bounds-checked functions, `localtime_s` is only guaranteed to be available if `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` is defined by the implementation and if the user defines `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` to the integer constant 1 before including `time.h`.

требуется проверка наличия дефайна `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` и задания после этого пользовательского дефайна `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` в единицу. Всё это нужно выполнить до подключения заголовочного файла `time.h`.

Иначе, функция может отсутствовать в реализации конкретного компилятора.

Comment: Определил оба упомянутых макроса, но диагностика осталась прежней.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 первый надо проверять, а не определять. Если его нет в системе, то ничего не выйдет. Можно ещё ‘_r‘ функцию проверить.

Comment: А с какой версии GCC можно ожидать, что в системе определена функция localtime_s? Чтобы не перебирать попусту все старые версии GCC?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 судя по всему такой версии просто не существует ещё.

Comment: Получается, что Microsoft использует нестандартную функцию, которую никто кроме них не поддерживает.

Answer (score 1):

В современных версиях Visual C++ CRT функция `localtime` (как большинство других подобных функций) не имеет проблем с доступом из разных потоков: используемый буфер не является настоящей статической переменной, а размещен на самом деле в локальном хранилище потока. Это не значит, что хорошо ее использовать - это просто очень неудачно спроектированный API, с которым легко допустить ошибки. Но таких в С/С++ много, это ни о чем не говорит.

Насколько я знаю, студия на такие функции дает предупреждение, а не ошибку. Вероятно, у вас включена опция компилятора "обрабатывать предупреждения как ошибки". Вы можете отключить предупреждение директивой `#pragma warning(disable : 4996)`, если у вас хватит дисциплины при этом не использовать **действительно** небезопасные функции из CRT, вроде `strcpy`. Либо переписывать код с использованием безопасных функций, доступных в конкретных компиляторах.

Что касается `localtime_s`, она введена в стандарте С11, который считается "экзотикой", и не все реализации в полной мере его поддерживают. В С++11 ее нету. GLIBC (аналог CRT в GCC) содержит вместо нее `localtime_r` из POSIX. Чтобы писать код, который будет обрабатываться разными компиляторами, придется воспользоваться условными директивами препроцессора и написать разные ветки кода для разных компиляторов. Иначе никак.